# Send JSON Data from Controller to View in Blade: Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

**Below is the class that returns Country data**

```
class CountryData {
    public function GetCountries() {
        return response()->json(['Data' => \App\Models\CountryModel::all()]);
    }
}
```

**I have following Json Data returned by above function**

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Type: application/json 
{
    "Data":[
              {
                  "CountryID"  : 1,
                  "Country"    : "United States",
                  "CountryCode": "US"
              }
           ]
}
```

**Below is the code in Controller.**

```
$Countries = (new \App\DataAccess\CountryData())->GetCountries();
return view('Country.List')->with('Countries', json_decode($Countries));
```

**Below is the code in View**

```
@foreach($Countries["Data"] as $Country)
    <tr class="odd pointer">
        <td class=" ">{{$Country["Country"]}}</td>
        <td class=" ">{{$Country["CountryCode"]}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

When I type `echo $Countries;` I get above text. When I type `echo json_decode($Countries, true);` It shows blank. Can you please guide me why this is happening?

Reason I am doing this because data is being passed into Blade using below code.

```
$Countries = (new \App\DataAccess\CountryData())->GetCountries();
return view('Country.List')->with('Countries', json_decode($Countries));
```

Comment: So, what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to read Json Data to show list of records in Blade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should be the controller code:

```
return view('Country.List')->with('Countries', $Countries->getData()->Data);
                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But I am not sure if this is correct way to fix this issue. I am reading `JsonResponse`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add true in the json_decode($data,true) function.
Change this

```
$Countries = (new \App\DataAccess\CountryData())->GetCountries();
return view('Country.List')->with('Countries', json_decode($Countries));
```

Change to

```
$Countries = (new \App\DataAccess\CountryData())->GetCountries();
return view('Country.List')->with('Countries', json_decode($Countries,true));
```

View

```
@foreach($Countries["Data"] as $Country)
    <tr class="odd pointer">
        <td class=" ">{{$Country["Country"]}}</td>
        <td class=" ">{{$Country["CountryCode"]}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```